# How to pass reference to function with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference

I have a data member that is of type:

```
std::function<T(T&, T&)>&
```

The constructor accepts an argument of the same type.

How should I send such a function using lambdas?

I've tried

```
MyClass tmp([](Foo &a, Foo &b) { return a+b; }, ...);
```

But it fails.

For example:

main.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass a([](int x, int y) { return x+y;});

    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(std::function<int(int, int)>&) noexcept;
    private:
        std::function<int(int, int)>& fun;
};
```

Comment: Fails how? Make a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you need to pass a non-`const` *reference* to a `std::function`?

Comment: @nwp: Fails in the way that passing a prvalue to a function taking a non-`const` reference fails.

Comment: @nwp Sorry, I added what you asked.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, try the example I posted.

Comment: @NicolBolas @nwp this is the error that bugs me:  `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘main()::<lambda(int, int)>’ to ‘std::function<int(int, int)>&’|`

Comment: Does `MyClass a([](int a, int b) { return a+b;});` in main need another "int"?

Comment: @Marichyasana The first `int` is the returnt type I think.

Comment: But you have 2 ints in main, but 3 in header.

Comment: @Marichyasana No, `a` is type `MyClass`. I've edited for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a lambda to a `std::function &`. A lambda is not a `std::function` so that doesn't work directly. However, a lambda is convertible to a `std::function`, so a temporary `std::function` has to be build that holds the lambda.

Since you are taking a `std::function &` C++ assumes you want to modify that value, otherwise there would be no point in taking it by non-const reference. Modifying a temporary has no effect, so this doesn't make sense, so C++ doesn't allow it.

One way to fix the issue is to take a `const std::function &`. That way there is no modifying of a temporary.

Another way is to pass an actual `std::function` that you create in `main`.

Another way is to create a template that just forwards it's argument to the `std::function`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        template <class T>
        MyClass(T &&t)
            : fun(std::forward<T>(t)){}
    private:
        std::function<int(int, int)> fun;
};
```

That way `MyClass` takes anything and uses it to construct `fun`. Note that `fun` is not a reference anymore. The `std::function` has to live somewhere and since it is part of `MyClass` it makes sense to tie the lifetime of the `std::function` to `MyClass`.

If you really want `fun` to be a reference you need to find a place for it and make sure it stays there until after `MyClass a;` gets destroyed. I do not recommend this route since it gets increasingly difficult to make sure the lifetimes are correct.

You can also store the lambda directly, but that is a bit tricky and depending on what you actually want to do with `MyClass` it may not be viable.

Comment: "Another way is to create a template that just forwards it's argument" -- There's really no advantage of that over just taking a `std::function` by value, and move-constructing `fun` from that. Or even your earlier suggestion of taking it by `const &` and copy-constructing from that. What you've done means type traits can no longer detect that `MyClass` isn't constructable from `int`, as the constructor instantiation would fail far too late for SFINAE to kick in.

Comment: @nwp I tried a temporary function like this: `auto fun = [](int x, int y)-> int& { return x+y;};`
 But it doesn't work.

Comment: @user6180573 I meant something like `std::function<int(int,int)> f = [](int x, int y) { return x+y;};` and then `MyClass a(f);`.

Comment: @user6180573 That's because the type of `fun` is not `std::function`. You need to specify `std::function<int(int, int)> fun = [](int x, int y) { return x+y; };`

Comment: @nwp Now it doesn't work for the above constructor :(

Comment: @nwp I had a typo, that's it! Thanks for getting me out of this mess.